# add rows when running out of white rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to add rows after the absolute last row, if the difference between the absolute last row and the last written row is less than or equal to 20. Only if the edited sheet is one or more predefined sheets.
The automatic execution was enabled when the sheets were modified.

The problem is that the code is not executed when making the modification, and if I execute it directly it only modifies the first sheet, without respecting the names of the sheets defined to be executed or the active sheet.

```
function test3() {
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  if( sheet.getActiveSheet().getName() == "test" ) return;

  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var lastRow = dataRange.getLastRow();
  var rawlengthsheet = sheet.getRange("B1:B").getValues();
  var lengthsheet = rawlengthsheet.length;
  Logger.log(lastRow)

  if ((lengthsheet -20)<lastRow){
      sheet.insertRowsAfter(lengthsheet, 20);
      sheet.appendRow(['']);
  }
}
```

Comment: About `only modifies the first sheet`, I think that when `sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` can be used as the active sheet when the script is run at the active sheet. So, for example, how about modifying as follows? From `sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); if( sheet.getActiveSheet().getName() == "test" ) return;` to `sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); if( sheet.getSheetName() == "test" ) return;`? But, I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 0):

The sheet modification trigger works with the help of @tanaike, but the editing restriction of specific sheets still does not work

```
function test3() {
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  if( !(sheet.getSheetName() == "test") && !(sheet.getSheetName() == "test2") ) return;
  var lengthsheet = sheet.getRange("B1:B").getLastRow()
  var testlengthcolumnB = sheet.getRange("B"+(lengthsheet-20)).getValue()
  Logger.log(testlengthcolumnB)
  
  if (testlengthcolumnB != ""){
      sheet.insertRowsAfter(lengthsheet, 20);
      sheet.appendRow(['']);
    }

}
```

Comment: First, I deeply apologize that from your question, I couldn't notice your issue of `the editing restriction of specific sheets still does not work`. Can I ask you about the detail of `the editing restriction of specific sheets still does not work`?

Comment: thank you very much for your help. the workbook has several sheets, I want it to only run on specific ones

Comment: for example, I want it to only run if the sheet name is "name1" or "name2": if( (namesheet !== "name1" || namesheet !== "name2")) return; but no work

Comment: my problem was a logical notation, I had to use && instead of ||. Thank you very much for the help

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your 2nd issue was resolved. About your updated script, when `if( !(sheet.getSheetName() == "test") && !(sheet.getSheetName() == "test2") ) return;` is modified to `if(!["test", "test2"].includes(sheet.getSheetName())) return;`, the process cost might be able to be reduced a little.